# Implementation of binary search algorithm

Tags: search, binary

I am getting an index error for a larger data set using this binary search function. When I input a smaller data set i.e. [1,2,3,4,5] searching for 5. the algo runs as expected. However when I take the text below, call the split method for the string object with a null list of parameters (delimeter char is ' ') and break the string into a list value where each element is a string, and search for the word 'culpa' I end up with the following error:

IndexError : list index out of range

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

string:
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

code:
http://ideone.com/TXVfQA

```
def binary_search(l,skey,start,stop):
    length = (stop - start) + 1 # length of search space
    middle = start + (length / 2)
    mid_val = l[middle]
    if skey == mid_val:
        return middle
    elif skey > middle:
        return binary_search(l,skey,(middle + 1),stop)
    else:
        return binary_search(l,skey,start,(middle - 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this algorithm.

First, if you request item smaller than smallest in list (`skey < l[start]`), then it loops.
Second, when `skey not in l[start:stop]`, then search falls with index out of bounds.

You have no appropriate behavior for case where element is not presented in list. You could, for example, return `None` if element is not found. Your code could be fixed that way:

```
def binary_search(l, skey, start, stop):
    # possible answer is always in interval [start, stop)
    while start + 1 != stop:
        middle = (start + stop) // 2
        mid_val = l[middle]
        if skey < mid_val:
            stop = middle
        else:
            start = middle
    return start if l[start] == skey else None
```

It will find last occurrence of element equal to `skey`. It also uses loop instead of recursion, saving time needed to execute a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're never checking to see if `stop` is less than `start`. Your recursive calls will easily create that condition.